# Having trouble reading Pandas dataframe with SciLearn Kit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm new to Python, and I am having trouble using SciLearn Kit on dataframes created using Pandas. Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt
import json
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_json('C:/Users/Desktop/Machine Learning/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json', lines=True, orient='columns', encoding='utf-8')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

list(dataframe)
subset_data = dataframe.loc[(dataframe.city == 'Toronto')]
print(subset_data)
documents = subset_data.to_dict('records')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer

no_features = 1000

# NMF is able to use tf-idf
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, max_features=no_features, stop_words='english')
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
tfidf_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# LDA can only use raw term counts for LDA because it is a probabilistic graphical model
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, max_features=no_features, stop_words='english')
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

Below is the error I get.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

The dataset is available here : [kaggle.com/yelp-dataset/yelp-dataset](http://kaggle.com/yelp-dataset/yelp-dataset)
Dataset:yelp_academic_dataset_business.json

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're passing a dictionary named documents to TfidfVectorizer. Since 'dict' doesn't have a method or attribute 'lower', I think that's why you're seeing this message. TfidfVectorizer expects a list, file or array of documents, not a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jarad, You have to feed a `list` or `series` to tfidf_vectorizer. Hence, the fix to your issues is

```
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(subset_data[records])
```